# What is the cause of this error I was getting?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getattribute

I'm using JavaScript to populate an HTML page with content. One of those pieces of content is a button/link. The content is generated dynamically, and when the user presses the button I will need to acquire some information that has been embedded (as an attribute) in the button itself.

Here's the general code:

```
var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "image";
button.src = "/images/image.png";
button.setAttribute("customData", "dynamically generated data");
button.setAttribute("onclick", "CustomFunction(this);");
newCell.appendChild(button);


CustomFunction(obj) {
      var data = obj.getAttribute("customData"));
};
```

When I get into the function (by pressing the button), the browser throws an error along the lines of `cannot getAttribute of null object`.

But it seems to work if I get rid of `button.src`.

I've already found a way around this, but I would like to know what causes this issue?

EDIT:
Here's the actual code:

```
var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "image";
button.src = "/images/image.png";
button.setAttribute("customData", "dynamically generated data (JSON format)");
button.setAttribute("onclick", "CustomFunction(this);");
newCell.appendChild(button);

function CustomFunction(obj) {
    buttonObj = obj.querySelector('input[type=image][customData]');
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(buttonObj.getAttribute("customData"));
};
```

Comment: i would start with printing the arguments out.  So, the first line of the function say:  `console.log(arguments);` to see what is available.

Comment: The line `var data = obj.getAttribute("customData"));` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/bdzd11w5/) after the syntax errors are fixed and the example is completed. You need to post an actual working example if we're going to explain what went wrong, including which implementations give this behavior.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't create custom attributes like that. Use standard `data-XXX` attributes.

Comment: @Barmar - I tried saying that in an answer, but was accused of being "off topic" ... go figure, right

Comment: @JaromandaX Indeed, it's not a solution to his problem. That's why I put it in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: really? additional information to teach a noob how to use javascript more effectively is off topic - must remember that, don't drag noobs out of 90's javascript meth0ds

Comment: @JaromandaX: The information is appreciated but staying on topic with answers is also appreciated.

Comment: @squint opinion noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
buttonObj = obj.querySelector('input[type=image][customData]');
```

`querySelector` searches the descendants of the given element for an element that matches the selector. But the element you're looking for is the same as `obj`, not one of its descendants.

Your code will work if you put the click handler on the cell rather than the button.

```
newCell.setAttribute("onclick", "CustomFunction(this);");
```

or

```
newCell.addEventListener("click", function() {CustomFunction(this);});
```

Or you can simply make `buttonObj` the argument to `CustomFunction()`, instead of using `querySelector()`.